# Multiple generics in one interface

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make some kind of parser, that parse data fields, and make it into a full form as well as to display it. `fields` property will define each field in json data array that client will receive from `url` property at `IForm`

The example of form interface goes like these below:

```
export interface IForm {
    name: string;
    url: string;
    fields: IField<any>[] // <-- What is the proper type of this?
}

export interface IField<T> {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    mandatory?: boolean;
    default: T;
}

export interface IInput<T> extends IField<T> {
    type: 'input'
}

export interface IOptionsUrl {
    url: string;
    idField: string;
    labelField: string;
}

export interface IOptionsList<T> {
    id: T;
    label: string;
}

export interface IOptions<T> extends IField<IOptionsList<T>> {
    type: 'options';
    options?: IOptionsUrl | IOptionsList<T>[] | string[];
    multiple?: boolean;
}

export interface ICheckbox extends IField<boolean> {
    type: 'checkbox'
}
```

The `fields` property at `IForm` will contain multiple type, such as `IField<string>` or `IField<number>` and so on. They are determined by `type` property in each type, all based on IField. So I am not sure, if I should put `<any>` since it will contain multiple types of data at the array. What is the proper way to define it? Or should I skip generics all together and just use any?

The sample data would be like this:

```
let meta: IForm = {
    name: 'employee',
    url: '/api/employee',
    fields: [
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'id',
            label: 'Employee ID',
            default: 0,
            mandatory: true
        },
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'name',
            label: 'Employee Name',
            default: '',
            mandatory: true
        },
        {
            type: 'options',
            name: 'gender',
            label: 'Male/Female',
            default: 'male',
            options: ['Male', 'Female']
        },
        {
            type: 'checkbox',
            name: 'active',
            label: 'Active',
            default: true
        },
        {
            type: 'options',
            name: 'department',
            label: 'Department',
            default: 0,
            options: {
                url: '/api/departments',
                idField: 'id',
                labelField: 'name'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

With employee interface would be:

```
export interface IEmployee {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    gender: string;
    active: boolean;
    department: number;
}
```

How should I define the interface for IForm?

Thank you

Comment: `IField<any>[]` and `Array<IField<any>>` [are synonymous according to the Array documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html). You could create your own [Union Type / Type Alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) like `type formType = string | number | boolean | date;`.  Then use `IField<formType>`.

Comment: Yes, but <any> will have all those string, number, boolean and date at the same time in one array.

Comment: `any` covers *more* than just those 4, so if you want to have type safety don't use `any`.

Comment: How do you intend to use `IForm`?  What type guarantees do you expect from its `fields` property?  Maybe you can edit this into a [mcve] so that someone can advise you on what to do.  There are more strongly-typed solutions in which `IForm` is itself generic, but the complexity might not be needed depending on your use cases.

Comment: @jcalz just added sample data.

Comment: @ErikPhilips That, I know. Therefore I am asking here, how can I specify it other than just `<any>`.

Comment: I guess the use case I'm interested in is what you will do with `meta`; specifically the `meta.fields` property.  Do you need the compiler to remember that `meta.fields[2].options` exists without checking it first?  Or do you plan to loop over each element of `meta.fields` and do different things depending on its `type` property.  As a first guess I'd say you should compile a union of possible actual `IField<T>` types you will use (e.g., `ICheckBox | IInput<string | number | boolean> | IOptions<string | number | boolean>`) and use an array of that for the `fields` type.

Comment: @jcalz I see.. Thank you. I think that would be more appropriate. Yes, I plan to loop over each element and show a proper form for that field. The option meta.fields[2] will make the list of 2 options in a combobox when it is displayed. Male and Female. The url at meta.fields[4] will show the same, but will retrieve from `/api/department' for its list.

Comment: @jcalz can you put it as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest, at least given the above info, that you do something like this:

```
type PossibleDataTypes = string | number | boolean; // or whatever you want

type PossibleFields =
  | IInput<PossibleDataTypes>
  | IOptions<PossibleDataTypes>
  | ICheckbox;

export interface IForm {
  name: string;
  url: string;
  fields: Array<PossibleFields>;
}
```

Here we are narrowing `field` to be an array of just the field types you expect.  You can add to this list if you want.

I made another change, by the way:

```
// changed this from IField<IOptionsList<T>> to just IOptionsList<T>
export interface IOptions<T> extends IField<T> {
  type: "options";
  options?:
    | IOptionsUrl
    | ReadonlyArray<IOptionsList<T>>
    | ReadonlyArray<string>;
  multiple?: boolean;
}
```

because your `meta` variable doesn't match without it.  Also I think `meta` had a typo where it used `data` instead of `url`.  Anyway you can define `meta` as an `IForm` as you did, but widening a variable to `IForm` will make it forget about particulars (like which particular field types you're using). If you just want to *verify* that `meta` matches `IForm` without widening it to `IForm`, you can use a helper function like this:

```
const asIForm = <F extends IForm>(f: F) => f;
```

And then use it like

```
const meta = asIForm({
  name: "employee",
  url: "/api/employee",
  fields: [
    {
      type: "input",
      name: "id",
      label: "Employee ID",
      default: 0,
      mandatory: true
    },
    {
      type: "options",
      name: "gender",
      label: "Male/Female",
      default: "male",
      options: ["Male", "Female"]
    },
    {
      type: "checkbox",
      name: "active",
      label: "Active",
      default: true
    },
    {
      type: "options",
      name: "department",
      label: "Department",
      default: 0,
      options: {
        url: "/api/departments",
        idField: "id",
        labelField: "name"
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Now, given the fact that `PossibleFields` is a concrete [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), you can then get the compiler to narrow each `field` entry via a type guard, as in:

```
function processForm(form: IForm) {
  for (let field of form.fields) {
    switch (field.type) {
      case "input": {
        // do something for input
        break;
      }
      case "checkbox": {
        // do something for checkbox
        break;
      }
      case "options": {
        // do something for options
        field.options // <-- no error, known to exist
        break;
      }
      default:
        ((x: never) => console.log("WHAT IS" + x))(field); // guarantee exhaustive
        // If an error appears here -------------> ~~~~~
        // then you missed a case in the switch statement
    }
  }
}
```

Okay, hope that helps you.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIBECGwcAq4ECUAvFAsAE7IB2A5lAD5R0CuAtqhNS1KjhxMOOgG4AUKEixEKDBABiyCOgAmpMhKj8Akrrph2wADzwkaTLnxFICAHza9AeTDBkcOgjNzL2PITEDk6sugDCABYQAMYA1oIAHpISEAlgcNTAUPTAvABmONHQuooZnFAA3k50OJwQAFyUNPQMkjrs1OiNVLSMbVB5KuoIjQCC1NQ4ID4WCsqqGvaSAL4S0Z5UUDgIJWXkUCaKUKm5dBpQu9Sc9gAUeY2KAJTk9gPJqemZ2XS51AVFF3m6hMBFeVR0NTq3WafSc6BwPC6TV6rScnFEajwGRAAH5GoJhBBRP01BACux0MBGgQVhIUmkMlkcvlCsUDEZTKDjglTucSkM1CCwU5pA0oAAiegc8W0+mfJk-FkA3SudwbACqnUqTg6SJ6LX6yDUQLU0JR-XhiJNZoNElWcsZ31+-2Kqo8XgAMsgqELtTojdSLQjVDbYfaAPThqDRCKiBgQNRQYARb0Dahwcr8hYmFVud0IL0+0GvYBwKAAK3Ym1zas93s5jg+juZf1ZFzdG19JwgZ1IWeBXPBSeIjXFcDzGxlTnHtYQeKcOlCHa8mvQC-440m0xr+cLDccOkXUE3UxM+sYSzRFPcYEweIEQhE4jtdKbXxbLoukRi8TgCW5vJ9iaJgEk+wo6KKo4xj+iRTva6xeFkdT4Ps2yXJwNxDpCYrihAnC3nAIAQBA4oADQ6p0o7hjgYDIOGeEEURJHkTogwLCMUAANrrkOh7DpAo5SsYZHrhCtQ4UaIl8TolohhKACi+HoIRxEXFgUnSaS5KUo0AAMLHSeiZxYtQICNDQ7AQOuywGTovGHpBEozvmGl8dho7xmcvCuYeslIuKACyOCYOGih4cFzGiVAWk4Neo7opgPk6M5GyNJxgURWREphQlJEALrWbZfrSY54rQXEsFFWJUISoU7gAG6RdJUB+aOozRA1TWaWSsU6Um1CWYVPFRaVKVeElbDiaOpJgDgmR1D8E2tRKWAQLN809sAE0xXFUD6VFY0cfZfG6lRNF0TNc3AAtwAIBN-rGgKglqPdLXBug1oSth4pRasfF-VABXLI8yR5OwdAde6UBgOmRRIKUVx3GUjToc8Q55BkUA3JgWRseoUBwHkAxlAAdHjGho+uCAAO7IMAMZY+TJOipTzXRNs0CSoYwmNMdh6RtFZYIBmEDJi0xN8EJwBRToqDUESsT9P9UXswgnPlb+CTirzMtQALahCyLYuMBL0ZRBVf663LCtK4eAN8arnOHdrxXNfrhvISmJsY3wh260zh161GJgALQh2wZa8Om1CkVAsR0HA1N0EmkcJPWVvyzgiu-VFO06brNw3AkjR0BAjXUM8ZCvAhwuYCTykMDc4oAOoABKjAQFwAMrilAADUUAJI8jx3AKINB1ADDsHNoi5NAqSxlWnW6wLuhE6IxwTJjNGQHNpBRPLUBh8fJ8n68AB+l+XyvUbJj2UAgHA7BQJw3pq4mODRhz3xJlElC0-TCITQ8B4U2tZJwqxVhAA)

Comment: Wow.. Thanks a lot.. That would fix many things. I don't use Date, since I have a specific IDate for date with ranges and ICheckbox for boolean. But this is enough for me to work on. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the types use a [Type Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
type formType = string | number | boolean | date;
export interface IForm {
  name: string;
  url: string;
  fields: IField<formType>[] // <-- What is the proper type of this?
}



let form.default = "adsf";     //valid
let form.default = 1;          //valid
let form.default = true;       //valid
let form.default = new date(); //valid
let form.default = null;       //in-valid
let form.default = undefined;  //in-valid
let form.default = never;      //in-valid
```

Comment: Ok.. so can I define fields: IFields<string> at first element, then IFields<number> at second, then IFields<boolean> at third with that?

Comment: Can you fix the typos in this code?  It will not compile.  (`date` is presumably supposed to be `Date`, and I really don't know what `let form.default =` is supposed to be...)